# PDF files downloaded with Python cannot be opened in acrobat

Tags: python, pdf, urllib2

I have a little python script that I am using to download a whole bunch of PDF files for archiving. The problem I have is that when I download the files, they appear correctly under the correct title, but they are the wrong size and they can't be opened by Acrobat, which fails with an error message saying `Out of memory` or `Insufficient data for an image` or some other arbitrary Acrobat error. Viewing the content of the page in a text editor looks a bit like a PDF document, by which I mean it is incomprehensible in general but with a few fragments of text and markup, including PDF identifiers.

The code to download the file is this:

```
def download_file( file_id):
    folder_path = ".\\pdf_files\\"
    file_download="http://myserver/documentimages.asp?SERVICE_ID=RETRIEVE_IMAGE&documentKey="    
    file_content = urllib.urlopen(file_download+file_id, proxies={})
    file_local = open( folder_path + file_id + '.pdf', 'w' )
    file_local.write(file_content.read())
    file_content.close()
    file_local.close()
```

If the same file is downloaded through a browser it looks fine, but is also larger on the disk. I am guessing that the problem might be to do with the encoding of the file when it is saved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write it as a binary file so:

`file_local = open( folder_path + file_id + '.pdf', 'wb' )`

Comment: Yep. The reason for this is that in text mode, Python will mangle newlines to make them match your platform's line ending standard. On Windows, this will change every LF to CR+LF.

Comment: @glenatron Using urllib.urlretrieve reduces your code to one line

Comment: @JonClements Thanks, this is one of my first dabblings in Python so I have no idea how to work idiomatically with it yet.